# How to build a hash of directory names as keys and file names as values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have directories with files and I would like to build a hash of directory names as keys and file names as values. Example:

```
/app/foo/create.json
/app/foo/update.json
/app/bar/create.json
/app/bar/update.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "foo" => {
    "create.json" => {},
    "update.json" => {}
  },
  "bar" => {
    "create.json" => {},
    "update.json" => {}
  }
}
```

Currently I'd doing this:

```
OUTPUT ||= {}

Dir.glob('app', '**', '*.json')) do |file|
  OUTPUT[File.basename(file)] = File.read(file)
end
```

But it's not working as expected, I'm not sure how to get the parent directory name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dir.glob('*/*.json', base: 'app').each_with_object(Hash.new {|g,k| g[k]={}}) do |fname,h|
  h[File.dirname(fname)].update(File.basename(fname)=>{})
end
  #=> {"foo"=>{"create.json"=>{}, "update.json"=>{}},
  #    "bar"=>{"update.json"=>{}, "create.json"=>{}}}
```

@Amadan explains the use of [Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob), which is exactly as in his answer. I have employed the version of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that invokes a block (here `{|g,k| g[k]={}}`) when `g[k]` is executed and the hash `g` does not have a key `k`.<sup>1.</sup> See also [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`), [File::dirname](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-dirname) and [File::basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-dirname).

The steps are as follows.

```
a = Dir.glob('*/*.json', base: 'app')
  #=> ["foo/create.json", "foo/update.json", "bar/update.json", "bar/create.json"] 
enum = a.each_with_object(Hash.new {|g,k| g[k]={}})
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["foo/create.json", "foo/update.json", "bar/update.json",
  #                  "bar/create.json"]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first value is generate by the enumerator and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values by the process of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
fname, h = enum.next
  #=> ["foo/create.json", {}] 
fname
  #=> "foo/create.json" 
h #=> {} 
d = File.dirname(fname)
  #=> "foo" 
b = File.basename(fname)
  #=> "create.json" 
h[d].update(b=>{})
  #=> {"create.json"=>{}}
```

See [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). The next value is generated by `enum` and passed to the block, the block variables are assigned values and the block calculations are performed. (Notice that the hash being built, `h`, has been updated in the following.)

```
fname, h = enum.next
  #=> ["foo/update.json", {"foo"=>{"create.json"=>{}}}] 
fname
  #=> "foo/update.json" 
h #=> {"foo"=>{"create.json"=>{}}} 
d = File.dirname(fname)
  #=> "foo" 
b = File.basename(fname)
  #=> "update.json" 
h[d].update(b=>{})
  #=> {"create.json"=>{}, "update.json"=>{}}
```

Twice more.

```
fname, h = enum.next
  #=> ["bar/update.json", {"foo"=>{"create.json"=>{}, "update.json"=>{}}}] 
d = File.dirname(fname)
  #=> "bar" 
b = File.basename(fname)
  #=> "update.json" 
h[d].update(b=>{})
  #=> {"update.json"=>{}} 

fname, h = enum.next
  #=> ["bar/create.json",
  #    {"foo"=>{"create.json"=>{}, "update.json"=>{}}, "bar"=>{"update.json"=>{}}}] 
d = File.dirname(fname)
  #=> "bar" 
b = File.basename(fname)
  #=> "create.json" 
h[d].update(b=>{})
  #=> {"update.json"=>{}, "create.json"=>{}} 
h #=> {"foo"=>{"create.json"=>{}, "update.json"=>{}},
  #    "bar"=>{"update.json"=>{}, "create.json"=>{}}}
```

<sup>1. This is equivalent to defining the hash as follows: `g = {}; g.default_proc = proc {|g,k| g[k]={}}`. See [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).</sup>

Comment: really appreciate your detailed answer, was wondering how do I set file content using `File.read` instead of empty hash as a value?

Comment: came up with this: `h[File.dirname(fname)].update(File.basename(fname)=>File.read("app/#{fname}"))` not quite sure it's a right way

Comment: also, how can I assign the hash output to a constant? smth like:
`OUTPUT ||= {}; OUTPUT[File.dirname(fname)] = File.read(fname)` instead of creation a new hash

Comment: I believe `File.read("app/#{fname}")` is correct. You could simply write `OUTPUT = Dir.glob...end`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to regexp:

```
output =
    Dir.glob('*/*.json', base: 'app').
    group_by(&File::method(:dirname)).
    transform_values { |files|
      files.each_with_object({}) { |file, hash|
        hash[File.basename(file)] = File.read(file)
      }
    }
```

Note the `base:` keyword argument to `File.glob` (or `Pathname.glob`, for that matter) which simplifies things as we don't need to remove `app`; also that for the purposes of OP's question there only needs to be one directory level, so `*` instead of `**`.